# SNSのアカウント価値の計算アルゴリズムについて

Tags: アルゴリズム

アルゴリズムの相談なんですがやや抽象的な話で
純粋なプログラミング技術の話ではなくここでしていい質問かわからないんですが
（だめなら消します）

**SNSのアカウントクオリティみたいなのを数値化したいと思っています**

---

例えばツイッターを例にあげると

フォロー数　フォロワー数　開始日時

の３つがすぐ手に入り
一応時間をかければ　ツイート数　やリプ数　RT数　
個々のツイートの被Fav数や被RT数みたいなのも計算できます

これらの情報からそのアカウントの
「**価値＝発信するツイートに価値がある、フォローするメリット**」
というものを計算したいです

※ここでいう「アカウントクオリティ」とは発信する情報の価値であって
「知名度や影響力＝その人に宣伝をさせるとどれだけたくさんの人にみてもらえるか」

というのとは少し違って
登録からまもない人とかフォロワーが少なくても
ひっそり価値の高い情報を発信してるみたいなことを計算したいです

時間がたてば一致することにはなると思いますが
成長途中のアカウントでも価値をいち早く判断したいです

---

純粋にフォロワー数だけで判断すると
例えばツイートの価値は同じでも
フォロー返ししかしない人と自分からフォローする人では
フォローワー数ってかわりますよね

何もしなければ同じ時間で同じ数フォローされる人でも
自分からフォローする人だと無条件で返してくれる人が何人とかいて
**ツイートクオリティは同じなのにフォロワー数では違いが出ます**

かといって**フォロー数フォロワー数の差や比を使ったとしても**
フォロー返しする人としないで同じフォロワー数でもフォロー数に差が出るので
差や比を使うとたくさん**フォロー返してる人の価値が低くなってしまいます**

被Favや被RTに関しても基本的にフォロワー数の母数に依存するので
同じ価値のツイートでもフォロワー数によって多くなってしまいます
（ツイッターに関しては時間が経てば拡散されてある程度価値基準にはなりそうですが）

また個々のツイートを考え出すと純粋に価値の高いツイートだけをたまにする人と
たまにいいことを言うけど価値の低いツイートもたくさん垂れ流す人もいるので

人によってたまにいいことをいえば普段は何つぶやいててもいいって人もいれば
価値のないツイートは邪魔だと考える人もいて
そこを統一的に計算するのは難しいので
やっぱり「フォローしたい度」ということでフォロワー数ベースで考えたくはあるんですが
純粋にフォロワー数だけを使ってしまうと
先にのべたようにフォロー返しや能動的フォロー頻度で差が出てしまうという問題があります

一番いいのは「先にフォローされた数 / アカウント運用期間」
みたいなのがわかればいいんですが
フォローフォロワー関係の時間情報は取得できません

---

**すでに使われてるそういう計算指標や論文があったりしないでしょうか

あるいは思いつきでもいいのでアイデアがあったら教えていただきたいです**

まだ企画段階で具体的な用途等は決まってないんですが
今の所人事採用や業務適正判断等の利用をぼんやり考えていて
計算時間は１アカウントあたり数時間～１日ぐらいはかかってもいいかなと言う感じです
（個々のツイートを遡るのにどの程度ツイッターサーバーに負荷かけていいのか未調査ですが迷惑にならない程度に取得できる情報で計算したいです）

応用的にスパム垢判断とか、
うもれてるおすすめアカウントを紹介したりにも使えるかなと思っていますが
その場合もうちょっと短時間で大量のアカウントに対して計算できればなおうれしいです

Answer (score 0):

思いつきですが
フォローを厳選してる人にフォローされている＝価値が高い

ということでフォロワーの (フォロワー数 / フォロー数) の平均をとるのはどうでしょうか
フォロワー割合の高い人＝フォローを厳選している人
なのでそういう人にフォローされてる＝質が高い
ということになる気がします

フォロワーが辿れないSNSでは無理ですが
Twitterのようにフォロワーが辿れるSNSならば計算可能です

Comment: フォロワーのFF比平均だと有象無象によって価値のある人がフォローしていても結果的には下振れしてしまいそうです。正規分布するかどうかはわからないですが、標準偏差の上の外れ値がどれだけかが逆に重要になる気がします。